# Reactive extension for Javascript (rxjs) map mismatch return type for Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, timer, rxjs, observable

Following [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-observables-increasing-interval?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) stackBlitz, I have tried to emit a series of N numbers, delaying each emission with a delay time which is function of the number itself. Here's the code

```
var subscription = Observable.from(Array.apply(null, {length:N}).map(Number.call, Number))
.pipe(map((iteration) => {
  return timer(iteration)
    .pipe(map(()=>iteration))
}))
.pipe(concatAll())
.subscribe((mappedIteration)=>{
    console.log(Number(mappedIteration)); // prints 0, 1, 2 ... 
})
```

The `mappedIteration` variable is of type Observable<{}>.
My questions are:

1) why the cast `Number(mappedIteration)` works on a type Observable<{}> and successfully prints the numbers `0,1,2,`?

2) why, give the behaviour in 1), `mappedIteration` is not of type `number`, as it happens in the stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-observables-increasing-interval?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) ?

3) is there a more straightforward method to 'map' a source of values into an Observable of arbitrary type (like a timer, in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, in particular a lot of `apply` and `call` usage, and those usually muddy the waters of typescript's type system(especially because their typed versions have only just been added in TS 3.2, which was released this week)

For your third question,

> 3) is there a more straightforward method to 'map' a source of values into an Observable of arbitrary type (like a timer, in this case)?

Yes, that would be to use the [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator; However, switchMap will "switch" the source observable into a new one for every emission, discarding previous values. In your specific example you might be more interested in the [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) operator: it will allow you to create new observables based on the source emissions, following the order of the previous observable. So the following observables will only begin when the previous ones have completed.

Finally, the [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) operator allows you to "start" your observables and let them run even if the previous ones werent completed yet, such that they run in parallel. I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rijpd7) where you can try them out, in a similar way to the one you've linked.

I recommend you to read [this blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511) that explains how these operators(and others) works with nice animations.

Comment: Using `concatMap` I can  solve the problem 2) and I successfully map a source of number into a source of numbers whose emission is delayed in time according to their value.